# Посчитать возраст, то есть число лет с даты рождения

Tags: php

Подскажите как посчитать возраст человека или кого-либо еще? То есть число лет с даты рождения.

Comment: Нужно - делайте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в каком таком абстрактном параграфе и ровно через год от какой даты?

Comment: К примеру есть дата 2000/01/01 то есть человеку сейчас 22 года, как сделать так, чтобы каждый последующий год к числу 22 прибавлялось +1.

Comment: в данном конкретном "к примеру", надо не к 22 прибавлять каждый  год единицу, а посчитать возраст человека на данный момент времени.

Comment: Так вот я прошу код, который бы сделал это

Comment: так вы как то пытались самостоятельно решить сей вопрос, в чем загвоздка то? задача, вроде как, не сложная. есть у вас дата рождения, скажем, в середине года `2000-06-01` и три произвольных даты  для проверки случаев `2000-12-01` (ноль лет) `2020-05-01` (19 лет) `2020-07-01` (20 лет). Первый пример даты должен бы дать понимание, что надо взять из дат годы и вычесть. Вторые два примера должны дать понимание. что надо учесть, прошел ли уже этот день в году или нет

Comment: Нашел решение кому надо будет то <?php
 function calculate_age($birthday) {
  $birthday_timestamp = strtotime($birthday);
  $age = date('Y') - date('Y', $birthday_timestamp);
  if (date('md', $birthday_timestamp) > date('md')) {
    $age--;
  }
  return $age;
}
 echo calculate_age('1990-01-01');
 ?>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3776682/4928642

Answer (score 1):

```
$age = date_diff(date_create($bdate), date_create('now'))->y;
```

Но осторожно с форматами даты.

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103977/4928642